# ReadAsDataContract<String[]> - Unexpected End of File

Tags: c#, wcf, http, rest

I have a program that calls a rest service and gets back a string array. When I try to read the string array I get an exception Unexpected end of file. If I have the service return a string containing just the first item of the array it works. What am I missing about `ReadAsDataContract<>()` that is causing this exception?

```
    var returnElement = response.Content.ReadAsDataContract<string[]>();
```

The exception is an XMLException: Unexpected End of File.

Stack trace-

```
at System.Xml.EncodingStreamWrapper.ReadBOMEncoding(Boolean notOutOfBand)
       at System.Xml.EncodingStreamWrapper..ctor(Stream stream, Encoding encoding)
       at System.Xml.XmlUTF8TextReader.SetInput(Stream stream, Encoding encoding, XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas quotas, OnXmlDictionaryReaderClose onClose)
       at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.ReadObject(Stream stream)
       at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractContentExtensions.ReadAsDataContract[T](HttpContent content, DataContractSerializer serializer)
       at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractContentExtensions.ReadAsDataContract[T](HttpContent content)
       at RestConsumption.Program.GetDevices() in **********\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\RestPractice\RestConsumption\Program.cs:line 55
       at RestConsumption.Program.Main(String[] args) in *********\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\RestPractice\RestConsumption\Program.cs:line 26
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

Comment: I can't show my full code, but I can show you how I'm using ReadAsDataContract.

Comment: What format is the response json, xml, ?

Comment: Are you sure the size of the web services response is not more than the max size limit set in your web config

Comment: @labroo No, I'm not, how can I check the max size limit in my program?

Comment: What does your DataContract class look like?

Comment: @JamesKyburz I'm not sure I have one

Comment: @JamesKyburz - The `DataContract` he is using is `string[]`. I don't know that this can be done this way (how would the `DataContractSerializer` know what to put in a `string[]`?)

Comment: Mmm What does you rest WebGet method look like?

Comment: Not sure really. This might not be related, but for your HttpClient object, you can try setting the TransportSettings.MaximumResponseHeaderKB property according to this post http://forums.asp.net/t/1407304.aspx/1

Comment: @labroo I messed around with it and it didn't seem to help, the array I'm trying to get is only 10 items that are all small strings. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this in a really easy way that I still don't understand why it worked. I simply did

```
    string[] returnElement = response.Content.ReadAsDataContract<string[]>();
```

instead of

```
    var returnElement = response.Content.ReadAsDataContract<string[]>();
```

and it worked fine. If anyone tells me why this worked I'll give them credit for answering this question.